# What is the difference between "deterrent" and "deterrence"?

Tags: differences, nouns

Can they be used interchangeably?

Today I wrote "deterrences" but my spell checker underlines it. Did I use it wrong or is the plural simply missing here?

Comment: "Deterrent" is countable "deterrence" is uncountable. In any case the words have different meanings. It would help if you gave some context. What are you actually trying to say? Do you have a complete sentence?

Comment: @WillBriggs They translate to the same word in German (*Abschreckung*). Merriam-Webster says "deterrent - relating to deterrence" and makes no mention of plurality.

Comment: @musiKk I do not speak German, but I would be utterly amazed if the language is unable to distinguish *deterrent* from *deterrence*. It would be tantamount to not knowing the difference between *house* and *housing*, or *food* and *feeding*.

Comment: @WS2: why would it be so amazing? Related but distinct concepts are often conveyed by the same word; this applies to all languages. E.g., the English word "abbreviation" can refer to the process of shortening something, or the result of shortening something.

Answer (score 1):

A "deterrent" is some thing that deters, many of those are "deterrents, and "deterrence" is the process or act of deterring.

> Saddam Hussein thought the mere uncertainty of whether he had nuclear
>   weapons would be a **deterrent** against invasion.  He thought that
>   adding the possibility of chemical and biological weapons would be
>   additional **deterrents**.  None of this provided **deterrence**
>   against US military action against him.

Answer (score 0):

A deterrent is a person, place or thing that deters a person, place or thing.

A deterrence is a word used to refer to the act of something being deterred.

When a person goes to prison, they are deterred.  The walls, the bars, the locks, the entirety of the prison is a deterrent meant to deter criminals from leaving.

When a person is in prison, they are experiencing a deterrence.

> If it wasn't for the deterrence, I would just walk out of here.

Comment: While that is semantically true, it's worth pointing out that the often said phrase "prison is an effective deterrent to crime" actually refers to the threat of imprisonment being an effective deterrent to actually commuting crimes in the first place, not that prisons are effective at incarcerating criminals and therefore prevent crimes.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that deterrent means deterrent?  I don't fully understand your comment, to be honest.

Comment: I'm saying that your illustration of the word specifically refers to an uncommon coupling of the words "deterrent" and "prison".

Comment: Oh.  I tried to think of other example scenarios and prison just kind of stuck out the most.  I suppose I could have alluded to children being deterred from skipping class in school, or possibly even the deterrence of insects in the household.

Comment: Oh no, it's a fine illustration, just not a common one. That's why I didn't dispute it. I just wanted to point out the more common case people are likely to stumble across, so that they wouldn't be misled by it.